# Not able to retrieve my login credentials

Tags: php, laravel

I know this might sound easy, I downloaded a bootstrap admin template to make my work easier but am not able to work around the log in page. I am trying to retrieve information i inserted but can't be able to do so and I dont know why.

I get the following error:

> undefined index:name

I dont understand why its picking the insert function instead of the store function, here is my code:

```
<form id="login-form" method="POST" action="{{route('/login')}}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required class="input-material">                   
                         </div>
                    <div class="form-group">            
                      <label for="password">Password:</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required class="input-material" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    </div>  
                   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                      @if(Session::has('danger'))
                           <div class="alert alert-danger">
                             {{ Session::get('danger') }}
                           </div>
                      @endif
                    </div>    
                    <!-- This should be submit button but I replaced it with <a> for demo purposes-->
                  </form><a href="#" class="forgot-pass">Forgot Password?</a><br><small>Do not have an account? </small><a href="{{route('register')}}" class="signup">Signup</a>
```

*My controller*

```
public function store(){
       $rules = array(
            'email'    => 'required|email', // make sure the email is an actual email
            'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:6' // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 6 characters
        );

        // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('login')
                ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
                ->withInput(Input::except('password')); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
        } else {
                     // create our user data for the authentication
            $userdata = array(
                'email'     => Input::get('email'),
                'password'  => Input::get('password')
            );

            // attempt to do the login
            if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

                 return redirect::to('home');
            } else {        

                // validation not successful, send back to form 
                return Redirect::to('login');

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your question and which errors are u facing?

Comment: @DarkBee the error is undefined index:name in my controller although the function that contains the index is an insert function

Comment: the method chosen is going to be determined by the route you're posting to, which is "/login"... It's probably pointing to the insert method in the same controller. check your routes/web.php and look for the entry

Comment: @DarkBee thank you for editing the question. Please help

Comment: @Giovanni thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving a proper routes call perhaps.
you should call the Controller function from the routes.

something like this:

```
 `Route::post('login',myController@store');
```

as you are submitting a form. it's a post request.

Comment: I did thank you:now am having a problem with the logic hope i will work it out